# Unable to remove directory "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\". The directory is not empty

Tags: asp.net-core

I get an error message:

> Unable to remove directory "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\". The directory is not empty

I have been restarting my laptop, but that did not help

Comment: The question title isn't good. Obviously you have a problem and you are looking for a solution. It does not summarise the actual question. I suggest you to rewrite the title.

Comment: Why would you *want* to remove it? When did you see this error?

Comment: for me, cleaning and rebuilding the solution solved this issue

Comment: My situation may be rare but in case it helps anyone else, I had this same error after changing a Client-Side-Library version (of bootstrap). Cleaning solution and/or restarting VS didn't fix it. The issue, in fact, was that OneDrive was delaying or complicating the deletion/change so VS couldn't build/move on. Once OneDrive prompt (about "many files were deleted" or something) was dismissed (took few mins to show up) VS could build again. Guessing moving folder out of OneDrive would be smartest fix long term - but hey, I like multiple backups of my files.

Answer (score 3):

Visualstudio need's the "obj" folder to operate and will create it again and again, preventing it from being created would break your project!

If just don't want it in your source-control consider ignoring, for example if you use GIT create a *.gitignore* with: `/obj/*` to ignore the folder and its contents.
Or even better, download one, like for C# you could use [VisualStudio.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) you only have to rename it to *.gitignore*

Comment: Why "If you're beginner"? Do pros keep obj directory in source control?

Comment: "If you're a beginner and just don't want it in your source-control consider ignoring" is rather my assumption, since the questioner didn't specify his goal in anyway. i see that "If you're beginner" is more misleading though, so i'm removing it